# Pdf files are not displayed on chrome && firefox mobile browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, mobile, embed

I have the following code to embed a pdf file on my site:

```
´<object data="path_to_pdfFile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="500">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support have a PDF Plugin. Instead you can <a href="<?php echo $libro_detallado[6] ?>">Click here to download it</a></p>

    </object>´
```

..It works just fine on desktop browsers (firefox, chrome, iE and even on Safari) but it happens when i go to my smartphone, it doesn't display the content of my pdf file but shows the "This Plugins is not supported" instead or something like that. Sometimes it doesn't even show anything but a gray frame.

[image]

Last time i heard browsers are not using nothing with adobe but i'm not sure what to do todisplay my content on mobiles and tablets.